# поворот устройства на бок с картинкой в kivy

Tags: python, kivy

При повороте устройства на бок,приложение остаётся горизонтальным. Как запретить ему это, чтобы изображение тоже повернулось на бок ? 
В kivy

Без выключения автоповорота в андроиде.Некоторые приложения так умеют, например clean master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В файле спецификации `buildozer.spec` смотрите:

```
# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait
```